# Use of undeclared type 'TrailViewController' - trying to handle item details from list in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, list, touch

Another issue with learning.
I found this in Apple Dev documentation: [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/handling_row_selection_in_a_table_view)

My target is to handle one tap on my list of items. When I click I need to open edit window and handle which row I selected. I trying to put that solution into my code but I have no idea what is TrailViewController (I getting Chinese links at first Google search page). So I decided to put my code there. I getting error:

> Use of undeclared type 'TrailViewController'.

They appear after I adding this into my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedTrail = elements[indexPath.row]
       
       if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TrailViewController") as? TrailViewController {
           viewController.trail = selectedTrail
           navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
       }
   }
```

Full code from file below:
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var listOfItemsTableView: UITableView!
    
    var elements: [Element] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("recipes").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                var elementsTemp = [Element]()
                for doc in snapshot.documents {
                    if let itemName = doc.get("name") as? String {
                        elementsTemp.append(Element(name: itemName))
                    }
                }
                self.elements = elementsTemp
                self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "elementCell", for: indexPath) as! ElementCell
        
        cell.elementNameLabel.text = elements[indexPath.row].name
        
        return cell
    }
    
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedTrail = elements[indexPath.row]
       
       if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TrailViewController") as? TrailViewController {
           viewController.trail = selectedTrail
           navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
       }
   }
    
    @IBAction func addItemButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAddItemView", sender: self)
    }

}

class Element {
    var name = ""
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

## Update 1

Ok, I made some progress, but at this moment I can't navigate to EditItemViewController. This is how my code looks now:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var listOfItemsTableView: UITableView!
    
    var elements: [Element] = []
    var element: Element?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("recipes").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                var elementsTemp = [Element]()
                for doc in snapshot.documents {
                    if let itemName = doc.get("name") as? String {
                        elementsTemp.append(Element(name: itemName))
                    }
                }
                self.elements = elementsTemp
                self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "elementCell", for: indexPath) as! ElementCell
        
        cell.elementNameLabel.text = elements[indexPath.row].name
        
        return cell
    }
    
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedElement = elements[indexPath.row]
       
       if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EditItemViewControllerID") as? MainViewController {
           viewController.element = selectedElement
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    
    }
    
   }
    
    @IBAction func addItemButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAddItemView", sender: self)
    }

}

class Element {
    var name = ""
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And how my storyboard looks at this moment:

[image]

Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `UIViewController` named `TrailViewController` and add it as the class for a new `UIViewController` in your storyboard and you'll no longer get this error:

```
class TrailViewController: UIViewController {
    var trail: Element?
    // ...
}
```

Note: Also, don't forget to add the identifier for the new `TrailViewController` added in the storyboard as `"TrailViewController"` to get the `UIViewController` when calling `instantiateViewController(identifier:` in `didSelectRow` and perform navigation successfully.

Comment: Ok, I got a point, I don't changed class name, just changed value name in function: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedTrail = elements[indexPath.row]
       
       if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TrailViewController") as? MainViewController {
           viewController.trail = selectedTrail
           navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
       }
   } - Now error is: Value of type: 'MainViewController' has no member 'trail'

Comment: Add a trail property to the new view controller. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah okay, I need trail - mean element, ok I try again. Give me few minutes.

Comment: Still can't navigate to edit screen. At this moment nothing happens, no build error, no app crashing. Just after selection app still showing list. Current code: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedTrail = elements[indexPath.row]
       
       if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EditItemViewControllerID") as? MainViewController {
           viewController.element = selectedTrail
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
       }
   }

Comment: And of course I added Storyboard ID to new view controller